# which cc provider to choose in UK - worldpay or sagepage

Tags: payment-gateway

With 2 payment provider options Sagepay and Worldpay which integrates better with magento?

From what I see, Sagepay has an officially produced extension but has limited functionality on the free one.

Worldpay has a complete free extension but I have seen complaints it is not as good as it is not an official extension.

Has anyone any experience or thoughts on which is preferable?  No other provider is an option.

Comment: And interestingly enough, this is on the frontpage of HackerNews today: https://stripe.com/blog/introducing-stripe-uk

Comment: cool thanks!  they may be too expensive, Id have to look deeper.  A proper merchant account can be 1.5-2%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sage Pay free module works very well. The main limitations are that it doesn't have integrated PayPal support and that it can't do online refunds - you would need to process this in Sage Pay and create the credit memo separately. The paid for module provides this as well as support and other benefits.

The Sage Pay module is also a lot more flexible in how you present payment options to your customer - you have direct (customer stays on site), server, inframe, and form which will all be processed off site in various ways. WorldPay will mean you are always taken off site. There is also the ability to use tokenisation in Sage Pay which allows the customer to save their cards on the site.

Comment: great thanks.  Offsite is a no no so thanks for that clarity.  What I dont get is paypal integration?  Just use paypal as a separate payment option?

Comment: It's just another option I guess. You will need a level of PCI-DSS compliance on your server as well for direct. It's a bit of a grey area as Magento doesn't actually store the card details but they are in memory temporarily.

Comment: interesting.  Do all onpage payments have this issue - authorize etc or just sage?  Do you have a link so I can look deeper into this grey area?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Cardstream as they are an independent payment gateway in the UK and have many free commerce modules, including Magento, which are all free to use. Simply download the module you require from their website and away you go! Tokenisation and virtual terminal are free.

There are also various ways to integration such as iFrame.